# Why am I getting this error? AttributeError: type object 'bubbleSort' has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to make my own bubble-sort algorithm for learning purposes. I'm doing it by:

- Making a random array
- Checking if the first two indexes of the array need to be swapped
- it does this throughout the whole list
- and does it over and over until when looping through until the end it doesn't need to swap anything anymore then the loop breaks

but when I print any variable in the class it says that the class has no attribute of the variable.
this is my code right now

```python
from random import randint

class bubbleSort:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size # Array size
        self.array = [] # Random array
        self.sorted = self.array # Sorted array
        self.random = 0 # Random number

        self.count = 0
        self.done = False
        self.equal = 0
        while self.count != self.size:
            random = randint(1, self.size)
            if random in self.array:
                pass
            else:
                self.array.append(random)
                self.count += 1

    def sort(self):
        while self.done != True:
            self.equal = False
            for i in range(self.size):
                if i == self.size:
                    pass
                else:
                    if self.sorted[i] > [self.tmp]:
                        self.equal += 1
                        if self.equal == self.size:
                            self.done = True
                    else:
                        self.sorted[i], self.sorted[i + 1] = self.sorted[i+1], self.sorted[i]


new = bubbleSort(10)
print(bubbleSort.array)
```

This is what outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/musab/Documents/Sorting Algorithms/Bubble sort.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(bubbleSort.array)
AttributeError: type object 'bubbleSort' has no attribute 'array'
```

Comment: Should be `print(new.array)`. `array` is an attribute of class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bubbleSort` is a class type, each object of this class type has its own `array`. To access `array`, one must do it through a class object. `__init__` is called when creating a class object.

give the following a try:

```
bubbleSortObj = bubbleSort(10)  # create a bubbleSort object
print(bubbleSortObj.array)  # print the array before sort
bubbleSortObj.sort()  # sort the array
print(bubbleSortObj.array)  # print the array after sort
```

**Notes**

- In `__init__` you've got:

```
self.array = [] # Random array
self.sorted = self.array # Sorted array
```

In this case, `array` and `sorted` point to the same list and changing one would change the other. To make a copy of a list, one approach (among many) is to call `sorted = list(array)`

- If there are any local function variables you can remove the `self`, eg, `self.count = 0` can just be `count = 0`, as it's not needed again once it's used, and doesn't need to be a class member

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have a class called `bubbleSort` and an instance of this class called `new`, which you create using `new = bubbleSort(10)`.

Since `bubbleSort` only refers to the class itself, it has no knowledge of member fields of any particular instance (the fields you create using `self.xyz = abc` inside of the class functions. And this is good, imagine having two instances

```
b1 = bubbleSort(10)
b2 = bubbleSort(20)
```

and you want to access the array of `b1`, you need to specify this somehow. The way to do it is to call `b1.array`.

Therefore, in your case you need to `print(new.array)`.